# Set VerticalAlignment in an EventTrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, vertical-alignment, eventtrigger

How would i go about setting a property that doesn't seem to have an animation type associated with it?  Specifically, I'd like to change a control's `VerticalAlignment` whenever an `EventTrigger` is activated.  Here's my current status/failed attempt:

```
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="my:MenuHelper.MenuIsReversed">
          <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="VerticalAlignment" Storyboard.TargetName="Bouncy_Bar">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Top"/>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
   </EventTrigger>
```

Which yields this exception:

> Cannot animate the 'VerticalAlignment' property on a
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Border' using a
>   'System.Windows.Media.Animation.ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames'. For
>   details see the inner exception.

Inner exception:

> The animation(s) applied to the 'VerticalAlignment' property calculate
>   a current value of 'Top', which is not a valid value for the property.

I'm not sure if i'm improperly qualifying the `VerticalAlignment` type or if this is simply the wrong way to go about setting an atypical animation property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, for the quick answer of my own question.  I found that I wasn't laying out the `XAML` to specify the target type well enough.  Here was the working result:

```
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="pill:PillMenuHelper.MenuIsReversed">
          <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bouncy_Bar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[1].ScaleY" To="-1" Duration="0:0:.002"/>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="VerticalAlignment" Storyboard.TargetName="Bouncy_Bar">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <VerticalAlignment>Top</VerticalAlignment>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
   </EventTrigger>
```